# Use Rack::CommonLogger in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, logging, sinatra, rack, error-logging

I have a small web-server that I wrote with Sinatra.  I want to be able to log messages to a log file.  I've read through http://www.sinatrarb.com/api/index.html and www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html, and I see that Rack has something called Rack::CommonLogger, but I can't find any examples of how it can be accessed and used to log messages.  My app is simple so I wrote it as a top-level DSL, but I can switch to subclassing it from SinatraBase if that's part of what's required.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`Rack::CommonLogger` won't provide a logger to your main app, it will just logs the request like Apache would do.

Check the code by yourself: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/common_logger.rb

All `Rack` apps have the call method that get's invoked with the HTTP Request env, if you check the call method of this middleware this is what happens:

```
def call(env)
  began_at = Time.now
  status, header, body = @app.call(env)
  header = Utils::HeaderHash.new(header)
  log(env, status, header, began_at)
  [status, header, body]
end
```

The `@app` in this case is the main app, the middleware is just registering the time the request began at, then it class your middleware getting the [status, header, body] triple, and then invoke a private log method with those parameters, returning the same triple that your app returned in the first place.

The `logger` method goes like:

```
def log(env, status, header, began_at)
  now = Time.now
  length = extract_content_length(header)

  logger = @logger || env['rack.errors']
  logger.write FORMAT % [
    env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] || env["REMOTE_ADDR"] || "-",
    env["REMOTE_USER"] || "-",
    now.strftime("%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
    env["REQUEST_METHOD"],
    env["PATH_INFO"],
    env["QUERY_STRING"].empty? ? "" : "?"+env["QUERY_STRING"],
    env["HTTP_VERSION"],
    status.to_s[0..3],
    length,
    now - began_at ]
end
```

As you can tell, the `log` method just grabs some info from the request env, and logs in on a logger that is specified on the constructor call, if there is no logger instance then it goes to the `rack.errors` logger (it seems there is one by default)

The way to use it (in your `config.ru`):

```
logger = Logger.new('log/app.log')

use Rack::CommonLogger, logger
run YourApp
```

If you want to have a common logger in all your app, you could create a simple logger middleware:

```
class MyLoggerMiddleware

  def initialize(app, logger)
    @app, @logger = app, logger
  end

  def call(env)
    env['mylogger'] = @logger
    @app.call(env)
  end

end
```

To use it, on your `config.ru`:

```
logger = Logger.new('log/app.log')
use Rack::CommonLogger, logger
use MyLoggerMiddleware, logger
run MyApp
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Shouldn't the first line of MyLoggerMiddleware#call(env) be:
  env['rack.errors'] = @logger
?

Comment: Also, I don't want to log every request, just warnings and error messages.  But I'd like it to be configurable so that I can set the level of logging, as in "debug", "info", "warnings", "errors", ...

BTW - My app is not a Rails app.  There is no config.ru file.  It's a simple Sinatra app.

I was hoping to use an existing standard, but can't figure out what that is.  Maybe I have to take the CommonLogger you showed me and wing it on my own?

Comment: `config.ru` is a configuration file for Rack, not for Rails. Both Sinatra and Rails are Rack-based, so you can use `config.ru` in Sinatra applications as well.

Comment: The file link first posted here has changed. It is currently https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/common_logger.rb

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It has no effect on Sinatra or Rack logging.

Comment: Where is the Logger class (used in Logger.new) defined?

Answer (score 15):

In your `config.ru`:

```
root = ::File.dirname(__FILE__)
logfile = ::File.join(root,'logs','requests.log')

require 'logger'
class ::Logger; alias_method :write, :<<; end
logger  = ::Logger.new(logfile,'weekly')

use Rack::CommonLogger, logger

require ::File.join(root,'myapp')
run MySinatraApp.new # Subclassed from Sinatra::Application
```

Comment: i try your solution, and it works. i wonder why it have to be in config.ru?

Comment: a file things I'm not 100% on there, would you mind commenting on what/why some of the lines are there please?

Answer (score 2):

I followed what I found on this [blog](http://blog.tobiascrawley.net/2008/12/21/stepping-off-the-rails-part-2/) post - excerpted below

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

disable :run
set :env, :production
set :raise_errors, true
set :views, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/views'
set :public, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/public'
set :app_file, __FILE__

log = File.new("log/sinatra.log", "a")
STDOUT.reopen(log)
STDERR.reopen(log)

require 'app'
run Sinatra.application
```

then use `puts` or `print`.  It worked for me.

Comment: That works, but I'd really like to find out how to use Rack::CommonLogger to send messages formatted with timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ErrorLogger
  def initialize(file)
    @file = ::File.new(file, "a+")
    @file.sync = true
  end

  def puts(msg)
    @file.puts
    @file.write("-- ERROR -- #{Time.now.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")}: ")
    @file.puts(msg)
  end
end


class App < Sinatra::Base

  if production?
    error_logger = ErrorLogger.new('log/error.log')

    before {
      env["rack.errors"] =  error_logger
    }
  end

  ...

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Reopening STDOUT and redirecting it to a file is not a good idea if you use Passenger. It causes in my case that Passenger does not start. Read https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems#stdout-redirection for this issue.

This would be the right way instead:

```
logger = ::File.open('log/sinatra.log', 'a+')
Sinatra::Application.use Rack::CommonLogger, logger
```