# Sinatra Ruby app one line log per request with custom info

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have one app that is a Sinatra app. I would like to have the log of each request on one line, Currently only 1 line per request is shown(the request itself). But I want to append custom info to it.

This is my current line:

```
[02/Feb/2018:11:52:32 +0000] "GET /feed/name.csv HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.1620
2400:gh654:32:6532:0:0:a43e:404f, 0.0.0.0:2017 - - [05/Feb/2018:13:32:48 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 404 18 0.0676
2400:gh654:32:6532:0:0:a43e:414d, 0.0.0.0:2017 - - [05/Feb/2018:13:32:48 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 404 18 0.0041
```

I want to transform it in something like:

```
INFO  2018-03-02T14:03:36Z [main] [066843] [8a6e846f-45b7-433d-9d98-21c8c0766ad7] method=GET path= /some/path.csv format=csv action=action_name status=200 duration=459.97 view=154.94 db=172.96 user=user_id ip=user_id on=protocol_used agent=agent_used params=params_used
```

In the past to do this in rails applications I have used lograge but it seems it is not supported by sinatra apps.

Have you guys ever had to append custom info to the sinatra logs?

This is my configuration for logging:

```
configure do
  enable :logging
  file = File.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/log/#{settings.environment}.log", 'a+')
  file.sync = true
  use Rack::CommonLogger, file
  set :show_exceptions, true
  set :logging,  true

  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/log/#{settings.environment}.log")
end
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what Sinatra is logging now vs. what you want it to do?

Comment: It’s possible that the webserver you’re using is also logging the request, which could explain multiple lines per request.

Comment: I have updated the question @Joe

Comment: That's weird, this value should just be the ip: `2400:gh654:32:6532:0:0:a43e:404f, ip` so it's weird to see different IPv6 addresses and the string ", ip" there as well...

Comment: oh sorry i just replaced the ip with the word IP , the other string are random(they were there, i kept the form but changed the values) things I put also :D

Comment: My problem is that I can't find a library that will put on a single line all the info and the only way I can do it is on multiple lines which is not what I want at all

Comment: Is that syslog format?

Comment: This will probably answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/2240842/335847

Comment: seems so, will test it on monday and will let you know!

Comment: @iain but this would get me to write on 2 lines I think in the log. I would like to append it to the first line somehow

Comment: @LucianTarna Either monkeypatch/prepend the call to `log`, but as [Rack Commonlogger is so small](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/common_logger.rb) I'd copy it and change the bits I need changed to come up with my own logger. Rack::Syslogger sound good? :)

Comment: @iain ok, that was what I thought I just hoped there is a better way. Thank you! Please post it as the answer